# How to download older version of MonoDevelop?

Tags: monodevelop, monobjc

After I updated my MonoDevelop IDE to the latest version 3.0.1, my Monobjc project is not detected anymore. I tried reinstalling Monobjc, but the add-ins are not installed since they only support MonoDevelop 2.8.

[image]

The project browser shows the error:

```
MySolution
  MyProject (Load Failed)
    Unknown solution item type:{guid1};{guid2}
```

So, I am trying to roll-back MonoDevelop to the last stable version. I searched through the MonoDevelop website, but have not found any download archive for older stable versions.

Where can I get the stable MonoDevelop 2.8 package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Monobjc addins are not ready yet (as the time of writing) for MonoDevelop 3.0 as many things have changed in the parsing model (now based on NRefactory 5).

The latest MonoDevelop 2.8 package can be [download here](http://download.xamarin.com/monodevelop/Mac/MonoDevelop-2.8.8.4.dmg).

**UPDATE**: The Monobjc addins now support both MonoDevelop 3.0 and Xamarin Studio 4.0.